# kotlin RecyclerViewAdapter IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I've moved from Java to Kotlin and create this recyclerViewAdapter:

```
class MisPedidosAdapter(private val context: Context, private var pedidos: List<ParseObject>?, private val onMisPedidosClickListener: OnMisPedidosClickListener) : CustomRecyclerViewAdapter() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    when(getItemViewType(viewType)){
        STATIC ->return NoMisPedidosHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.no_pedidos_recibidos_item, parent, false))
        else -> return MisPedidosHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.mis_pedidos_item, parent, false), onMisPedidosClickListener, pedidos)
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if (getItemViewType(position) == STATIC)
    {
        val mHolder = holder as NoMisPedidosHolder
    }
    else
    {
        val mHolder = holder as MisPedidosHolder

        val pedido = pedidos!![position]
        val menuShop = pedido.getParseObject("menu_shop")
        mHolder.numPlati.text = pedido.getNumber("quantity")?.toInt().toString()
        mHolder.horario.text = pedido.getString("horario")

        mHolder.dateOrder.text = StringUtils.getDataFormatted("dd MMM yyyy", pedido.createdAt!!)

    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = when{
    pedidos!!.isEmpty() -> STATIC
    else -> DINAMIC
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = when{
    pedidos!!.isEmpty() -> 1
    else -> pedidos!!.size
}

fun updatePedidos(pedidos: List<ParseObject>) {
    this.pedidos = pedidos
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

companion object {
    private val STATIC = 0
    private val DINAMIC = 1
 }
 }
```

the problem is that, probably, when I do `list.size` in Kotlin it includes also the size index (for example, if the size is 4, it consider {0,1,2,3,4}). When I use for cycle I'm able to lock in {0,1,2,3} with `until`, but in this case I don't know how to do.
Anyone know a way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you return 1 when your list is empty?

Comment: I post for example a message with "No message received" @MuratK.

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = when{
    pedidos!!.isEmpty() -> 0
    else -> pedidos!!.size
}
```

**insted of this**

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = when{
    pedidos!!.isEmpty() -> 1
    else -> pedidos!!.size
}
```

Comment: no it's correct, because if pedidos.size == 0, it shows another view in the adapter

Comment: @nani share your crash log with question

Comment: answer is correct because adapter send position 1 to onBindViewHolder method and you try get first item from empty array: val pedido = pedidos!![position]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace

```
 when(getItemViewType(viewType)){
```

with

```
 when(viewType){
```

Comment: Indeed, and `viewType` is the second argument of the method `onCreateViewHolder`. Method `getItemViewType` just maps `position` to `viewType`. Humble question: have you tried the solution?

Comment: Just to confirm, you replaced within `onCreateViewHolder` method, correct?